# WAP Web Service returns different Session ID from Website

Tags: asp.net, web-services, sessionid

I am converting code from a Website Project (WSP) to a Web Application Project. I have a number of Webservices that are part of the site. Using WSP, the Session ID was common, but using WAP, the session ID is different between the Website and the web service. I need them to be the same. Is this possible using WAP?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This was one of those strange bugs that just disappeared. I don't know what I changed, but it appears that both the web site and the service share the same SessionID.

Answer (score 0):

Are you enabling session state in your Web Service?

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public string GetName()
{
   return (string)Session["MyName"];
}
```

Comment: Yes, I am including that line.